# How to override jwt_required function call for login route api call in before_request

Tags: python, flask, jwt

How to use @jwt_required decorator with @before_request for all api calls except for the '/login' api call. The jwt_required is imported from flask_jwt_extended package. I am not using flask blueprints. I want to avoid calling the decorator for all the API routes except for login. Using flask, python

Answer (score 1):

Use the verfiy tokens in request functions: https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#verify-tokens-in-request

An example might look something like this (unteseted)

```
from flask_jwt_extended import verify_jwt_in_request

@app.before_request
def before_request():
    if request.endpoint != 'login':
        verify_jwt_in_request()
```

Comment: thank you for the response. But in all other request api calls I will have to pass the current user value, which is what I want to avoid. In short I want to avoid explicitly passing of value. I have about 45-50 api calls.

Comment: You can still use `current_user`, `get_jwt_identity`, etc while using this method. This is exactly the same as using the `@jwt_required`. In fact, all the `@jwt_required` decorator is doing is wrapping the `verify_jwt_in_request()` function into a decorator: https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/blob/master/flask_jwt_extended/view_decorators.py#L91